# Bash Script Looping over line input

Tags: bash, loops

I'm doing the following, which basically works.
The script tries to insert some lines into a file to rewrite it.

But it is stripping all blank lines and also all line padding.
The main problem is that it does not process the last line of the file.
I'm not sure why.

```
     while read line; do
        <... process some things ...>
        echo ${line}>> "${ACTION_PATH_IN}.work"
     done < "${ACTION_PATH_IN}"
```

What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ## some work
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >> output
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$(cat input)")
```

- An empty IFS tells `read` not to strip leading and trailing whitespace.
- `read -r` prevents backslash at EOL from creating a line continuation.
- Double-quote your parameter substitution (`"$line"`) to prevent the shell from doing word splitting and globbing on its value.
- Use `printf '%s\n'` instead of `echo` because it is reliable when processing values like like `-e`, `-n`, etc.
- `< <(printf '%s\n' "$(cat input)")` is an ugly way of LF terminating the contents of `input`. Other constructions are possible, depending on your requirements (pipe instead of redirect from process substitution if it is okay that your whole `while` runs in a subshell).
  It might be better if you just ensured that it was LF-terminated before processing it.

Comment: If `IFS` has been set for the read, the last `printf` is not needed, as the `read` will actually read all the lines verbatim (including spaces), as `cat` just does nothing with the file contents but copy them to the pipe.

Comment: @Diego: `printf ' foo \n\n bar ' | bash -c 'while IFS= read -r line; do printf "<<%s>>\n" "$line"; done'` never processes the final non-LF terminated, “bar” line. The `printf` in the redirect from process substitution is there to add a trailing LF if-and-only-if the original content does not have one; it is not about preserving whitespace but making the last line be processed correctly.

Comment: @Diego: You are correct that `read` will read a final non-LF-terminated line, but it also returns non-zero, which exits the loop (thus such a line is never processed by the body of the loop).

Comment: Ahh, I see... It is important then to ensure the last line ends in a newline... Much easier :)

Answer (score 3):

Best yet, use a tool such as `awk` instead of the shell's `while` loop. First, `awk` is meant for parsing/manipulating files so for a huge file to process, `awk` has the advantage. Secondly, you won't have to care whether you have the last newline or not (for your case).

Hence the equivalent of your `while read` loop:

```
awk '{
  # process lines
  # print line > "newfile.txt"
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for not reading the last line is that the file does not end with a newline.  On the whole, I'd expect it to work even so, but that could be why.

On MacOS X (10.7.1), I got this output, which is the behaviour you are seeing:

```
$ /bin/echo -n Hi
Hi$ /bin/echo -n Hi > x
$ while read line; do echo $line; done < x
$
```

The obvious fix is to ensure that the file ends with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, use

```
echo "$line" >> ...
```

Note the quotes. If you don't put them, the shell itself will remove the padding.

As for the last line, it is strange. It may have to do with whether the last line of the file is terminated by a `\n` or not (it is a good practice to do so, and almost any editor will do that for you).